# Why won't my USB drive mount on OS X?

Tags: macos, usb, mount

I have a SanDisk 256GB Ultra Fit USB 3.1 Flash Drive and it stopped working on my MacBook. I've tried restarting the computer. The disk shows up in the Disk Utility tool but when I right click and select mount nothing happens.

Checking the console, I found the following error:

```
Mount of disk2s1 blocked by dissenter PID=0 (kernel) status=0x0000c001 (Operation not permitted)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the partition based on the discussion [on open radar].[1](https://openradar.appspot.com/25280285)

I used a a trial of [Hard Disk Manager by Paragon](https://www.paragon-software.com/hdm-mac/) to resize the partition and now it's readable again.